# FilePond for Vue / Nuxt : Server property set dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, server, nuxt.js, filepond

Little question:

```html
<file-pond
  name="customImage"
  ref="pond"
  label-idle="Déposez votre image ici"
  :allow-multiple="false"
  accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
  server="http://localhost:3000'"
  :files="custom.customImage"
  @init="handleFilePondInit"
/>
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the server value ?
For example :

```js
v-server="apiUrl+'/api/v1/upload'"
```

Comment: I've edited your answer with some code highlight and replaced the usual `v-on` by `@` and `v-bind` by `:`. Those are shortcuts, as shown here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands Hope it's fine, feel free to rollback if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```js
:server="`${apiUrl}/api/v1/upload`"
```

I'm using `:server` but it can be written as `v-bind:server` and [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for some better looking interpolation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kissu !

Comment: @VinParker my pleasure man! Enjoy your day.